# Is there a way to only have 3 numerical characters when formatting a currency using java

Tags: java, number-formatting

Is there a function in Java to format a currency amount so it only include a maximum of three numerical characters and an optional k, m or b if its thousands, millions or billions. Everything can be rounded up to at least $1 i don't care about the cents.

For example:
`354`
`23.2K`
`1.00M`
`20.1M`
`13.1k`
`21.1k`
`20.2M`
`1.01B`

Answer (score 0):

I thnk u need to create your own Class, something like:

```
Class Curr{
 int amount;
Curr(int x){
 amount=x;
}
toString(){
 if(amount/10000000>1)
  System.out.println(amount:1000000000 + "B");
 else if(amount/10000>1)
  System.out.println(amount:1000000 + "M");
 else if(amount/10)
  System.out.println(amount:1000 + "K");
 else
  System.out.println(amount);
}

}
```

Numbers in if are  smaller so, if u have for example 100 it will be shown as 0,1K.
You can edit so it suits your needs.